# C# Update ListView item without clicking on listview item row

Tags: c#, listview

I have a ListView with 3 columns (Item,Quantity,Price). I need to know if there is a way updating the item without clicking listView like when i click a button then it will find an specific item then it will update it

items exist in list view

```
Item       | Quantity | Price
Hotdog     |    1     |  20
```

so when i click the button "hotdog" it will update the listview item "Hotdog" and add 1 Quantity and add price? I dont have any code to start

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: First you need to get the `ListViewItem` that hold your expensive hotdog item like: `var lvi = lvw.FindItemWithText("Hotdog", false, 0);` Check if the function returns the required item: `if(lvi != null) { }`, if true then increase the quantity: `lvi.SubItems[1].Text =  (int.Parse(lvi.SubItems[1].Text) + 1).ToString();` and the price: `lvi.SubItems[2].Text =  (float.Parse(lvi.SubItems[2].Text) + 20).ToString();`

Comment: Ideally you would keep a list of the items that are shown in the listview, and build the listview from that list.  Then when you update an item in the list (eg. Hotdog +1) then you just rebuild the listview.  Think about it this way - listviews are for displaying data, not storing it.